# Cannot update MySQL from php

Tags: php, mysql, updating

I cannot for the life of me get my php to update my database. I've gotten it to insert but not update. Been going at this for over 2 hours. I just need a pair of fresh eyes! If someone can figure this out.. it would be a HUGE help. I'm probably making some small stupid mistake, but oh well. If I've left out something you'd like to see, please let me know. This is what it's going towards, [http://cbogausch.com/portal/](http://cbogausch.com/portal)

update.php

```
    <?php
    include("config/db.php");
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$sql = "UPDATE `secure_login`.`users` SET `link1` = \'$_POST[input_link1]\', `link2` = \'$_POST[input_link2]\', `link3` = \'$_POST[input_link3]\', `link4` = \'$_POST[input_link4]\', `link5` = \'$_POST[input_link5]\', `link6` = \'$_POST[input_link6]\', `link7` = \'$_POST[input_link7]\', `link8` = \'$_POST[input_link8]\', `link9` = \'$_POST[input_link9]\', `link10` = \'$_POST[input_link10]\', `link11` = \'$_POST[input_link11]\', `link12` = \'$_POST[input_link12]\', `pic1` = \'$_POST[input_pic1]\', `pic2` = \'$_POST[input_pic2]\', `pic3` = \'$_POST[input_pic3]\', `pic4` = \'$_POST[input_pic4]\', `pic5` = \'$_POST[input_pic5]\', `pic6` = \'$_POST[input_pic6]\', `pic7` = \'$_POST[input_pic7]\', `pic8` = \'$_POST[input_pic8]\', `pic9` = \'$_POST[input_pic9]\', `pic10` = \'$_POST[input_pic10]\', `pic11` = \'$_POST[input_pic11]\', `pic12` = \'$_POST[input_pic12]\', WHERE `users`.`user_id` = 1;";

mysql_query($sql);// or die mysql_error();
    }
    // class autoloader function, this includes all the classes that are needed by the script
    // you can remove this stuff if you want to include your files manually




    function autoload($class)
    {
        require('classes/' . $class . '.class.php');
    }

    // automatically loads all needed classes, when they are needed
    spl_autoload_register("autoload");


    //create a database connection
    $db    = new Database();

    // start this baby and give it the database connection
    $login = new Login($db);
    ?>
    <?php include('views/header/header.php'); 
    ?>
                    <div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:5%; background-color:#fff; box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); width:450px; height:45px;">
                            <div style="float:left; height:30px;">
                                    <img src="<?php echo "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5( strtolower( trim( $_SESSION['user_email'] ) ) ) . "?d=mm&s=40"; ?>" style="width:30px; height:30px; border-radius:15px; border:8px solid #ccc;" />                                
                            </div>      
                            <div style="float:left; height:30px; margin-left:10px; line-height:30px;">
                                <div style="font-size:12px; font-weight:normal;">Hey, <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?> (<span style="font-size:12px; color:red;"><?php echo substr($_SESSION['user_email'], 0, 15); ?>...</span>). You're logged in. <a href="settings.php">(Settings!)</a> <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?logout">(Logout)</a>   </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:60px; bottom:5%; left:5%; right:5%; background-color:#C0C0C0; box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); width:90%; height:100%; text-align:center;">
        <center>
        <?php echo $_POST["input_link3"] ?>
        <?php include('toggle.php'); ?>
        </br>
        </br>
        <?php include('quote.php'); ?>
        </br>
        </br>   
    <form method="post" action="update.php">
    <div style="background-color:white">
    <table width=75%; border-color=red; style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%; background-color:white; text-align:center;">
    <tr>
    <td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
        <b>Link #1</b>
        </br>
        Link URL: 
        <input id="input_link1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link1" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link1']; ?>" />
        </br>
        Link Image: 
        <input id="input_pic1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic1" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic1']; ?>" />
    </td>
    <td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
        <b>Link #2</b>
        </br>
        Link URL: 
        <input id="input_link2" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link2" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link2']; ?>" />
        </br>
        Link Image:
        <input id="input_pic2" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic2" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic2']; ?>" />
    </td>          
    <td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
        <b>Link #3</b>
        </br>
        Link URL:
        <input id="input_link3" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link3" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link3']; ?>" />
        </br>
        Link Image:
        <input id="input_pic3" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic3" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic3']; ?>" />
    </td>
    <td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
        <b>Link #4</b>
        </br>
        Link URL:
        <input id="input_link4" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link4" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link4']; ?>" />
        </br>
        Link Image:
        <input id="input_pic4" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic4" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic4']; ?>" />
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
        <b>Link #5</b>
        </br>
        Link URL:
        <input id="input_link5" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link5" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link5']; ?>" />
        </br>
        Link Image:
        <input id="input_pic5" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic5" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic5']; ?>" />
    </td>
    <td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
        <b>Link #6</b>
        </br>
        Link URL: 
        <input id="input_link1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link6" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link6']; ?>" />
        </br>
        Link Image: 
        <input id="input_pic1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic6" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic6']; ?>" />
    </td>
    <td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
        <b>Link #7</b>
        </br>
        Link URL: 
        <input id="input_link1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link7" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link7']; ?>" />
        </br>
        Link Image: 
        <input id="input_pic1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic7" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic7']; ?>" />
    </td>
    <td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
        <b>Link #8</b>
        </br>
        Link URL: 
        <input id="input_link1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link8" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link8']; ?>" />
        </br>
        Link Image: 
        <input id="input_pic1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic8" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic8']; ?>" />
    </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
        <b>Link #9</b>
        </br>
        Link URL:
        <input id="input_link5" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link9" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link9']; ?>" />
        </br>
        Link Image:
        <input id="input_pic5" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic9" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic9']; ?>" />
    </td>
    <td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
        <b>Link #10</b>
        </br>
        Link URL: 
        <input id="input_link1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link10" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link10']; ?>" />
        </br>
        Link Image: 
        <input id="input_pic1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic10" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic10']; ?>" />
    </td>
    <td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
        <b>Link #11</b>
        </br>
        Link URL: 
        <input id="input_link1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link11" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link11']; ?>" />
        </br>
        Link Image: 
        <input id="input_pic1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic11" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic11']; ?>" />
    </td>
    <td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
        <b>Link #12</b>
        </br>
        Link URL: 
        <input id="input_link1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link12" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link12']; ?>" />
        </br>
        Link Image: 
        <input id="input_pic1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic12" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic12']; ?>" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit">
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="index.php">Back to Main Page</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
    </center>
    </div>

    <?php include('views/footer/footer.php'); ?>
```

Here is my database connect

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST", "cboga*****.com");
define("DB_NAME", "secure_login");
define("DB_USER", "******");
define("DB_PASS", "******");
?>
```

Comment: nice mess in the code ;(

Comment: After such a Hollywood style creation of a scene, I expected a question in the end :) i.e. What's the error?

Comment: Well u are prone to hack attacks with this code. Better it didn't work in the first place.

Comment: where r u giving `mysql_query($sql)` ?

Comment: If any of those values is null and your table doesn't handle that, it could be causing the update problem.  So even if just one is null, it will screw up the entire update.  But I agree, this is dangerous code!!

Comment: Sorry, but a db called _"secure_login"_ that is being updated this insecurely is just hilarious, if it weren't tragic. for a kickoff, read up on prepared statements and google _"mysql extension deprecation php"_

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, lol !!!

Comment: please filter your input and escape your output, always, have a look at PDO for your db queries in future.

Answer (score 1):

you should actually execute your query with `mysql_query()` and please paste LESS code, limiting to where you are sure the problem is. I understand that you are not sure where exactly, but c'mon, that we are willing to help doesnt mean you get to lay back. Ow and please tidy up your code...

Answer (score 0):

Try now

```
<?php
include("config/db.php");
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$sql = "UPDATE `secure_login`.`users` SET `link1` = \'$_POST[input_link1]\', `link2` = \'$_POST[input_link2]\', `link3` = \'$_POST[input_link3]\', `link4` = \'$_POST[input_link4]\', `link5` = \'$_POST[input_link5]\', `link6` = \'$_POST[input_link6]\', `link7` = \'$_POST[input_link7]\', `link8` = \'$_POST[input_link8]\', `link9` = \'$_POST[input_link9]\', `link10` = \'$_POST[input_link10]\', `link11` = \'$_POST[input_link11]\', `link12` = \'$_POST[input_link12]\', `pic1` = \'$_POST[input_pic1]\', `pic2` = \'$_POST[input_pic2]\', `pic3` = \'$_POST[input_pic3]\', `pic4` = \'$_POST[input_pic4]\', `pic5` = \'$_POST[input_pic5]\', `pic6` = \'$_POST[input_pic6]\', `pic7` = \'$_POST[input_pic7]\', `pic8` = \'$_POST[input_pic8]\', `pic9` = \'$_POST[input_pic9]\', `pic10` = \'$_POST[input_pic10]\', `pic11` = \'$_POST[input_pic11]\', `pic12` = \'$_POST[input_pic12]\', WHERE `users`.`user_id` = 1;";

mysql_query($sql);// or die mysql_error();
    }
// class autoloader function, this includes all the classes that are needed by the script
// you can remove this stuff if you want to include your files manually




function autoload($class)
{
    require('classes/' . $class . '.class.php');
}

// automatically loads all needed classes, when they are needed
spl_autoload_register("autoload");


//create a database connection
$db    = new Database();

// start this baby and give it the database connection
$login = new Login($db);
?>
<?php include('views/header/header.php'); 
?>
                <div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:5%; background-color:#fff; box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); width:450px; height:45px;">
                        <div style="float:left; height:30px;">
                                <img src="<?php echo "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5( strtolower( trim( $_SESSION['user_email'] ) ) ) . "?d=mm&s=40"; ?>" style="width:30px; height:30px; border-radius:15px; border:8px solid #ccc;" />                                
                        </div>      
                        <div style="float:left; height:30px; margin-left:10px; line-height:30px;">
                            <div style="font-size:12px; font-weight:normal;">Hey, <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?> (<span style="font-size:12px; color:red;"><?php echo substr($_SESSION['user_email'], 0, 15); ?>...</span>). You're logged in. <a href="settings.php">(Settings!)</a> <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?logout">(Logout)</a>   </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:60px; bottom:5%; left:5%; right:5%; background-color:#C0C0C0; box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); width:90%; height:100%; text-align:center;">
    <center>
    <?php echo $_POST["input_link3"] ?>
    <?php include('toggle.php'); ?>
    </br>
    </br>
    <?php include('quote.php'); ?>
    </br>
    </br>   
<form method="post" action="insert.php">
<div style="background-color:white">
<table width=75%; border-color=red; style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%; background-color:white; text-align:center;">
<tr>
<td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
    <b>Link #1</b>
    </br>
    Link URL: 
    <input id="input_link1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link1" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link1']; ?>" />
    </br>
    Link Image: 
    <input id="input_pic1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic1" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic1']; ?>" />
</td>
<td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
    <b>Link #2</b>
    </br>
    Link URL: 
    <input id="input_link2" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link2" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link2']; ?>" />
    </br>
    Link Image:
    <input id="input_pic2" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic2" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic2']; ?>" />
</td>          
<td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
    <b>Link #3</b>
    </br>
    Link URL:
    <input id="input_link3" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link3" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link3']; ?>" />
    </br>
    Link Image:
    <input id="input_pic3" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic3" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic3']; ?>" />
</td>
<td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
    <b>Link #4</b>
    </br>
    Link URL:
    <input id="input_link4" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link4" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link4']; ?>" />
    </br>
    Link Image:
    <input id="input_pic4" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic4" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic4']; ?>" />
</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
    <b>Link #5</b>
    </br>
    Link URL:
    <input id="input_link5" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link5" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link5']; ?>" />
    </br>
    Link Image:
    <input id="input_pic5" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic5" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic5']; ?>" />
</td>
<td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
    <b>Link #6</b>
    </br>
    Link URL: 
    <input id="input_link1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link6" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link6']; ?>" />
    </br>
    Link Image: 
    <input id="input_pic1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic6" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic6']; ?>" />
</td>
<td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
    <b>Link #7</b>
    </br>
    Link URL: 
    <input id="input_link1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link7" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link7']; ?>" />
    </br>
    Link Image: 
    <input id="input_pic1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic7" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic7']; ?>" />
</td>
<td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
    <b>Link #8</b>
    </br>
    Link URL: 
    <input id="input_link1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link8" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link8']; ?>" />
    </br>
    Link Image: 
    <input id="input_pic1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic8" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic8']; ?>" />
</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
    <b>Link #9</b>
    </br>
    Link URL:
    <input id="input_link5" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link9" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link9']; ?>" />
    </br>
    Link Image:
    <input id="input_pic5" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic9" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic9']; ?>" />
</td>
<td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
    <b>Link #10</b>
    </br>
    Link URL: 
    <input id="input_link1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link10" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link10']; ?>" />
    </br>
    Link Image: 
    <input id="input_pic1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic10" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic10']; ?>" />
</td>
<td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
    <b>Link #11</b>
    </br>
    Link URL: 
    <input id="input_link1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link11" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link11']; ?>" />
    </br>
    Link Image: 
    <input id="input_pic1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic11" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic11']; ?>" />
</td>
<td style="border:2px solid black;max-width:100%;">
    <b>Link #12</b>
    </br>
    Link URL: 
    <input id="input_link1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_link12" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['link12']; ?>" />
    </br>
    Link Image: 
    <input id="input_pic1" class="settings" type="text" name="input_pic12" size="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pic12']; ?>" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>
    <input type="submit">
</td>
<td>
    <a href="index.php">Back to Main Page</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</center>
</div>

<?php include('views/footer/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: You should at least mention what you changed :)

Comment: Sorry ;).  He wasn't executing the query before.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Still not working. I'm not getting any errors, and I checked the users and I've given privileges to the user so that the user can select, insert, update, delete and file in the table. I'm not doing this for anything on a production scale, just trying to learn some mysql! But thanks for the comments.